# user not registered in moid_verto

Tags: webrtc, voip, freeswitch, mod-verto

I have registered 2 extension in FreeSWITCH, I am able to logging in with both extension also. But, when I am trying to call one to another extension, I am getting error of USER_NOT_REGISTERED in fs log. 
I am able to check status for both extension using `verto_contact dialed_user@dialer_domain`

```
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [INFO] mod_dialplan_xml.c:635 Processing FreeSWITCH User <1002>->1000 in context default
Dialplan: verto.rtc/1000 parsing [default->1000] continue=false
Dialplan: verto.rtc/1000 Regex (PASS) [1000] destination_number(1000) =~ /^(\d+)$/ break=on-false
Dialplan: verto.rtc/1000 Action bridge(${verto_contact ${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}) 
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:216 (verto.rtc/1000) State Change CS_ROUTING -> CS_EXECUTE
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1397 Send signal verto.rtc/1000 [BREAK]
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:528 (verto.rtc/1000) State ROUTING going to sleep
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (verto.rtc/1000) Running State Change CS_EXECUTE
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:535 (verto.rtc/1000) State EXECUTE
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] mod_rtc.c:120 verto.rtc/1000 RTC EXECUTE
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:258 verto.rtc/1000 Standard EXECUTE
EXECUTE verto.rtc/1000 bridge(error/user_not_registered)
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:2124 Parsing global variables
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [NOTICE] switch_ivr_originate.c:2759 Cannot create outgoing channel of type [error] cause: [USER_NOT_REGISTERED]
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3747 Originate Resulted in Error Cause: 606 [USER_NOT_REGISTERED]
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [INFO] mod_dptools.c:3276 Originate Failed.  Cause: USER_NOT_REGISTERED
2016-06-09 11:00:19.896037 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:4749 Hangup verto.rtc/1000 [CS_EXECUTE] [USER_NOT_REGISTERED]
```

My dialplan :

```
<include>
  <extension name="1000">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(\d+)$">
        <action application="bridge" data="${verto_contact ${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}"/>
    </condition>
</extension>
</include>
```

I have also added this lines in default.xml which is required :

```
<param name="dial-string" value="{^^:sip_invite_domain=${dialed_domain}:presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(*/${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})},${verto_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})}"/>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long reviewer, I am able to solve this issue. There was issue in dialplan which I have created. It was not taking extension_number in verto_contact. So, I have made change of 1 line in dialplan.

Changed Dialplan :

```
<include>
<extension name="ext_call">
<condition field="destination_number" expression="^(\d+)$">
<action application="bridge" data="${verto_contact $1@X.X.X.X}"/>
</condition>
</extension>
</include>
```

Thanks.