# FreeSwitch + Mode Verto + Webrtc + Android + unable to make call from android

Tags: webrtc, freeswitch, mod-verto

I have made a `mode-verto` android client, using **WebRtc**;

- Pre-built library: `org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+`
- libjingle: `io.pristine:libjingle:11139@aar`

and **FreeSwitch** but only got success to make uni-directional communication(SIP phone to an android client, voice communication in both devices successfully). But when I try to make a call from an android client to a SIP phone it doesn't work.

---

**Steps:**
From Web To mode-verto android Client(Working scenario):
**Login Call:**

```
{"method":"login","id":1,"params":{"passwd":"XXX","userVariables":{},"loginParams":{},"login":"1002@XXX.XXX.com","sessid":"0afc3741-97cf-4b59-94a4-57bdcc2f5f17"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

**Login Call Response:**

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"message":"logged in","sessid":"0afc3741-97cf-4b59-94a4-57bdcc2f5f17"}}

 {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":254,"method":"verto.clientReady","params":{"reattached_sessions":[]}}
```

**Call Invitation From Web:**

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":255,"method":"verto.invite","params":{"callID":"94c79b9e-9aa1-41d6-85be-3f94d71bf4f4","sdp":"v=0\r\no=FreeSWITCH 1633327591 1633327592 IN IP4 192.168.0.1\r\ns=FreeSWITCH\r\nc=IN IP4 192.168.0.1\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS esmOfEYFBQ88Oj5egBp9rex75ApyzBlE\r\nm=audio 16468 RTP/SAVPF 102 9 0 8\r\na=rtpmap:102 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:102 useinbandfec=1; maxaveragebitrate=30000; maxplaybackrate=48000; ptime=20; minptime=10; maxptime=40; stereo=1\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 30:D5:C6:44:1E:D6:22:FD:54:D1:0E:E8:7C:B4:E7:AD:93:99:E9:CD:48:D0:6D:B6:28:EE:19:45:83:8A:62:B8\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:16468 IN IP4 192.168.0.1\r\na=ssrc:2708468483 cname:UyjZ27vuNtssDnxJ\r\na=ssrc:2708468483 msid:esmOfEYFBQ88Oj5egBp9rex75ApyzBlE a0\r\na=ssrc:2708468483 mslabel:esmOfEYFBQ88Oj5egBp9rex75ApyzBlE\r\na=ssrc:2708468483 label:esmOfEYFBQ88Oj5egBp9rex75ApyzBlEa0\r\na=ice-ufrag:OMJ6Q73MxiaXJmsu\r\na=ice-pwd:KBkDyFYcZgvtuS29vC5czYOX\r\na=candidate:9757738161 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.0.1 16468 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:9757738161 2 udp 2130706431 192.168.0.1 16468 typ host generation 0\r\na=silenceSupp:off - - - -\r\na=ptime:20\r\na=sendrecv\r\nm=video 16470 RTP/SAVPF 96 98 100 102 127 125 108 124 123\r\nb=AS:3072\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000\r\na=fmtp:98 profile-id=0\r\na=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000\r\na=fmtp:100 profile-id=2\r\na=rtpmap:102 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:102 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f\r\na=rtpmap:127 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f\r\na=rtpmap:125 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:108 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=rtpmap:124 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f\r\na=rtpmap:123 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 30:D5:C6:44:1E:D6:22:FD:54:D1:0E:E8:7C:B4:E7:AD:93:99:E9:CD:48:D0:6D:B6:28:EE:19:45:83:8A:62:B8\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:16470 IN IP4 192.168.0.1\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:124 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:124 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 ccm tmmbr\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli\r\na=ssrc:1891818205 cname:UyjZ27vuNtssDnxJ\r\na=ssrc:1891818205 msid:esmOfEYFBQ88Oj5egBp9rex75ApyzBlE v0\r\na=ssrc:1891818205 mslabel:esmOfEYFBQ88Oj5egBp9rex75ApyzBlE\r\na=ssrc:1891818205 label:esmOfEYFBQ88Oj5egBp9rex75ApyzBlEv0\r\na=ice-ufrag:pWTWGFjyLZJAyUKz\r\na=ice-pwd:0XZUOcLk08IHnyICkspRXyfz\r\na=candidate:0896075528 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.0.1 16470 typ host generation 0\r\na=candidate:0896075528 2 udp 2130706430 192.168.0.1 16470 typ host generation 0\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\n","caller_id_name":"Extension 1001","caller_id_number":"1001","callee_id_name":"Outbound Call","callee_id_number":"1002","display_direction":"outbound"}}
```

**Call Response with SDP:**

```
{"method":"verto.answer","id":2,"params":{"dialogParams":{"callID":"94c79b9e-9aa1-41d6-85be-3f94d71bf4f4","remote_caller_id_number":"1002","destination_number":"1002","remote_caller_id_name":"1002"},"session_id":"0afc3741-97cf-4b59-94a4-57bdcc2f5f17","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 4285064094073427202 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS MediaStream\r\nm=audio 63288 RTP\/SAVPF 102 9 0 8\r\nc=IN IP4 192.168.2.1\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=candidate:341193750 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.8.101 49077 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10\r\na=candidate:1510613869 1 udp 2122129151 127.0.0.1 49460 typ host generation 0 network-id 1\r\na=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 192.168.2.1 63288 typ srflx raddr 192.168.8.101 rport 49077 generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10\r\na=ice-ufrag:BfLO\r\na=ice-pwd:RBsUQ\/uNeEiqmPgyvWJBN4vs\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:3A:73:40:49:34:6F:E6:F0:17:9F:E6:7F:FE:C1:0D:C0:3D:86:A1:28:39:73:3A:EB:64:67:E4:57:55:EA:C0\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:102 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=fmtp:102 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA\/8000\r\na=ssrc:2607788540 cname:lwXiQ5hT1hGGiwou\r\na=ssrc:2607788540 msid:MediaStream ARDAMSa0\r\na=ssrc:2607788540 mslabel:MediaStream\r\na=ssrc:2607788540 label:ARDAMSa0\r\nm=video 0 RTP\/SAVPF 96 98 125\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:OxRK\r\na=ice-pwd:LCVdU01PHZJFx4\/dv4j3nqdN\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 3D:3A:73:40:49:34:6F:E6:F0:17:9F:E6:7F:FE:C1:0D:C0:3D:86:A1:28:39:73:3A:EB:64:67:E4:57:55:EA:C0\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:video\r\na=inactive\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:125 H264\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli\r\na=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\n"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Followings are the messages received after successful call invitation response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"result":{"sessid":"0afc3741-97cf-4b59-94a4-57bdcc2f5f17"}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":259,"method":"verto.display","params":{"callID":"94c79b9e-9aa1-41d6-85be-3f94d71bf4f4","display_name":"Extension 1001","display_number":"1001","caller_id_name":"Extension 1001","caller_id_number":"1001","callee_id_name":"Outbound Call","callee_id_number":"1002","display_direction":"outbound"}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":260,"method":"verto.bye","params":{"callID":"94c79b9e-9aa1-41d6-85be-3f94d71bf4f4","causeCode":16,"cause":"NORMAL_CLEARING"}}
```

In the above scenario, the followings states are CONNECTED:

```
onStandardizedIceConnectionChange

onIceGatheringChange

onConnectionChange

onIceConnectionChange
```

---

**mode-verto to Web Platform/SIP (Scenario in which help is required):**

**Login Call:**

```
{"method":"login","id":1,"params":{"passwd":"XXX","userVariables":{},"loginParams":{},"login":"1002@XXX.XXXX.com","sessid":"9743f047-ba15-47ad-828b-26c57529fcf3"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

**Login Call Response:**

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"message":"logged in","sessid":"9743f047-ba15-47ad-828b-26c57529fcf3"}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":261,"method":"verto.clientReady","params":{"reattached_sessions":[]}}
```

**Call Invitation:**

```
{"method":"verto.invite","id":2,"params":{"dialogParams":{"callID":"50533ec8-985c-4857-99bf-bcb1b021e558","caller_id_name":"1002","remote_caller_id_number":"1001","destination_number":"1001","remote_caller_id_name":"Outbound Call","useVideo":false,"useStereo":false,"useMic":"any","login":"1002@XXXX.XXXX.com","useCamera":"any","screenShare":false,"tag":"any","caller_id_number":"1002","useSpeak":"any","videoParams":{"minHeight":"720","minFrameRate":30,"minWidth":"1280"}},"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 1985358600062838354 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS MediaStream\r\nm=audio 60367 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 37.111.135.112\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=candidate:341193750 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.2.1 49612 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10\r\na=candidate:1510613869 1 udp 2122129151 127.0.0.1 42121 typ host generation 0 network-id 1\r\na=candidate:842163049 1 udp 1686052607 37.111.135.112 60367 typ srflx raddr 192.168.2.1 rport 49612 generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10\r\na=ice-ufrag:DRth\r\na=ice-pwd:6ZrLWyqfDk4vqVPGktrUsCOw\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 DF:C1:F2:1E:F9:C6:9F:54:55:CD:A0:78:D5:85:23:B0:C7:E5:6A:C9:48:6C:4D:5E:17:5C:00:D4:F5:D0:D6:BF\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:audio\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http:\/\/www.ietf.org\/id\/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event\/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event\/8000\r\na=ssrc:859436163 cname:6xspDJIe1I+kt4ue\r\na=ssrc:859436163 msid:MediaStream ARDAMSa0\r\na=ssrc:859436163 mslabel:MediaStream\r\na=ssrc:859436163 label:ARDAMSa0\r\n","sessid":"9743f047-ba15-47ad-828b-26c57529fcf3"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

**Call Invitation Response:**

```
 {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"result":{"message":"CALL CREATED","callID":"50533ec8-985c-4857-99bf-bcb1b021e558","sessid":"9743f047-ba15-47ad-828b-26c57529fcf3"}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":263,"method":"verto.media","params":{"callID":"50533ec8-985c-4857-99bf-bcb1b021e558","sdp":"v=0\r\no=FreeSWITCH 1633328922 1633328923 IN IP4 172.1.0.165\r\ns=FreeSWITCH\r\nc=IN IP4 172.1.0.165\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS YfVYnQ98r94pqu4N6K4IJDNht8vLsWrg\r\nm=audio 17076 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 110\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=silenceSupp:off - - - -\r\na=ptime:20\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 30:D5:C6:44:1E:D6:22:FD:54:D1:0E:E8:7C:B4:E7:AD:93:99:E9:CD:48:D0:6D:B6:28:EE:19:45:83:8A:62:B8\r\na=setup:active\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:17076 IN IP4 172.1.0.165\r\na=ice-ufrag:VRYvkCDEAYgSKxZD\r\na=ice-pwd:zTJiNNjGMzQ6KDmvlbRwEk05\r\na=candidate:8820384080 1 udp 2130706431 172.1.0.165 17076 typ host generation 0\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ssrc:2909163670 cname:2c4fT3eb39qjtkXq\r\na=ssrc:2909163670 msid:YfVYnQ98r94pqu4N6K4IJDNht8vLsWrg a0\r\na=ssrc:2909163670 mslabel:YfVYnQ98r94pqu4N6K4IJDNht8vLsWrg\r\na=ssrc:2909163670 label:YfVYnQ98r94pqu4N6K4IJDNht8vLsWrga0\r\n"}}
```

**Call Invitation Ans. confirmation Response:**

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":264,"method":"verto.answer","params":{"callID":"50533ec8-985c-4857-99bf-bcb1b021e558"}}
```

After this process:
`onIceConnectionChange` and `onStandardizedIceConnectionChange` get stuck in `CHECKING` state and `onConnectionChange` in `CONNECTING` state.
and after few seconds, `onIceConnectionChange` , `onStandardizedIceConnectionChange` and `onConnectionChange`  states change to `FAILED`.

On the android client, it takes 30, 40 seconds to gather complete Ice-Candidates, which is a lot.
On exchange of successful SDP's , even after ice candidates completion, `onIceConnectionChange` and `onStandardizedIceConnectionChange` states change to `Failed`.

Also followed these solutions:

- [WebRTC + IOS + Freeswitch : Can't hear audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826464/webrtc-ios-freeswitch-cant-hear-audio)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881785/10413749
- [No audio when webrtc mobile clients connected in different network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622610/no-audio-when-webrtc-mobile-clients-connected-in-different-network)

But still, I do not get what I am doing wrong.

Is there anything I'll be missing which I should check? Any help from the community would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Did you get any help from the above link? The behavior of `FreeSWITCH` with `mod-verto` is somewhat `uni-directional in nature. If the `mod-verto` android application is behaving the same then it might be an issue with `FreeSWITCH + SIP Trunking` server. 

Here are some useful references might help:(https://stackoverflow.com/a/41117397/10413749), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734727/unable-to-make-webrtc-work-in-freeswitch) ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717674/user-not-registered-in-moid-verto ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717674/user-not-registered-in-moid-verto

Comment: I have also compared my remote SDP with

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64622610/no-audio-when-webrtc-mobile-clients-connected-in-different-network

and that is 100% match.

should I send my invitation to callee after **Ice-candidates** completion, also should I wait to send call invitation response after ice-candidates completion?

Comment: @MuhammadAoun just send the invite to sip trunck after 2-5 seconds once ice candidates are generated.im just waiting for 2 seconds for my ice candidates to generate.after that i get the sdp with current ice candidates and sent it sip trunck.my call gets connected.similarly i did for verto.answer.hope it helps

Comment: @Jeeva , Thankyou for replying, I have created a p2p app, using native webrtc library, and over there ice candidates get completed within a second. and I am using the same library in the mode-verto android client application, but then it takes 40 secs. to get complete. 

These are the logs for p2p application:
- https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai8SDD7HWsys13AH1r8IQSoSYx1Z
and these are the logs for mode-verto client application:
- https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai8SDD7HWsys129-J5Pk4hqj-pHR

Comment: @MuhammadAoun really sorry could not check your logs.but im not waiting for full ice candidates formed.so give it a try with 5 seconds and then forward

Comment: @Jeeva, I have tested multiple times, but while I am working on a simple p2p application, `Ice-candidates` gather completely within a sec. as you have mentioned. But when I integrated `mode-verto` functionality and try to run the process, `Ice-candidates` take around 40s.

and because of this after setting remote SDP, `onConnectionChange` stuck at connecting state.

It would be very helpful for me if you provide me with any assistance.

Comment: @MuhammadAoun hi bro im not a expert bro.what i did was i didnt wait until for full ice connection ,i sent the invite with sdp to sip trunk after 5 seconds and it worked.and for me onConnectionChange was stuck at connecting state only when my ice candidates were not connected properly.if possible try to use better ice and stun servers.

Comment: @Jeeva, is it possible, that you can send me your demo application? So that I can check where I am making mistakes.

That would be a great help for me. because I am stuck at this point for a while.

Comment: @MuhammadAoun no bro i dont have demo app .i was working on production app.this was a feature.

Comment: @Jeeva, can we communicate over some other platform. And if it's possible can you consult me, but I'll pay you for your consultation.